# How did my friend get a flimsy shovel without a recipe?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

I was helping my friend collect some bells to pay off their house loan (not tent) in Animal Crossing New Horizons.

We were making good use of the flimsy shovel until it finally broke.

The weird thing, he doesn't have the DIY recipe for building one.

He hasn't invited Blathers to his island yet, nor is the recipe available for purchase in the store. As far as I know, he hasn't been to any mystery islands either, and still has the Nook Miles ticket from upgrading to his house.

According to the [wiki](https://nookipedia.com/wiki/Item:Flimsy_shovel_(New_Horizons)), these are the only ways to get the Flimsy shovel. Unfortunately he doesn't remember how he got the shovel either.

We're in the process now of inviting Blathers to get the proper recipe, but I'm still at a loss as to how the original Flimsy shovel he has was obtained.

Does anyone else possibly know? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have the Nook store? In the Nook store, there is a cabinet in the back left that should sell tools if you interact with it (the back left for the first iteration of the store, which you'd likely have at this point in the game). Possibly bought it from there? Also, when you take the crafting tutorial from Tom Nook, he also gives you some 'starter' recipes, which I believe include the flimsy tools. If you go to a workbench, is the flimsy shovel one of the recipes you can make?

Comment: @king14nyr Thanks for the response. No, the flimsy recipe shovel wasn't one of the recipes we could make at a workbench. And no, Nook's Cranny hasn't been built yet, just the small store at Resident Services. My best guess is it was obtained from someone else's island via online play.

Comment: Hmm yeah without either of those 2 available, the only other thing I can think of is from somewhere off island.... from someone else's as you mentioned, or possibly from Nook Island tours with DAL? I know you can buy tools from Wilbur for some miles when your on tour, but based on where you are, not sure you got to this point yet.